# Pronunciation of single-syllable words ending in -ost

Tags: pronunciation

In Modern English, there are several monosyllabic words ending in -ost, like "most", "cost", "post", "lost", "frost".  Assuming RP, some of them are pronounced  with /əʊ/ (post) and others with /ɒ/ (cost).

At first, I guessed (at least for nouns) that Germanic words might use the former pattern and more Latin(-ish) the latter. But "post" got so wild etymology for the multitude of its meanings... And, for example, "frost" easily breaks the rule. I didn't check any Middle/Old English spellings.

Are there any rules/patterns/hopes to derive pronunciation from spelling here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find any rule that relates the spelling of words containing "ost" to the pronunciation of the vowel. I don't think it would be of much practical use anyway: since there are so few words with this spelling pattern, it seems easier to just memorize that *cost, frost, lost* are pronounced with /ɒst/ and *ghost, host, most, post* are pronounced with /əʊst/. (In fact, because there are so few monosyllabic words that end in *-ost,* I'm also going to discuss the pronunciations of some polysyllabic words ending in *-ost*.)

For the most part, the modern differences in pronunciation correspond to historical differences in pronunciation, but a few words seem to have undergone irregular sound changes.

- Old English *āst* /ɑːst/ seems to regularly correspond to Modern English /oʊst/, as in *most* < Old English *māst,* *ghost* < Old English *gāst,* *[oast](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=oast)* < Old English *āst.* There doesn't seem to be any reason why some of these words are spelled with *ost* and others with *oast.*
- Old English *ost* /ost/, or *os* /os~oz/ contracted with a following dental plosive, seems to regularly correspond to Modern English /ɒst/ (or in different accents, /ɔst/ or /ɑst/), as in *frost* < Old English *frost.* (There are historical spellings of *frost* that show that variant developments also once existed, such as forms with a long vowel or a metathesized form *forst.*) The final consonant cluster in *lost* seems to have developed in Middle English; the Old English verb *losian* "lose" had the past participle *(ge)losod.*
- a unique (as far as I can tell) word from Old English is *dost,* which has the same /ʌ/ vowel as *does, doth, done.* This seems to be the result of vowel reduction in a very commonly used verb. (Compare the change in many forms of North American English, but generally not in British English, of the vowel in the stressed forms of common words like *was, what, of, because* to /ʌ/.)
- French *ost* was generally taken into English as long /oʊst/ (*post* < French *post; host* < French *(h)o(o)st; toast* < French *toster; roast* < French *roster; coast* < French *coste*). The development seems similar to that of words like *beast* < French *beste*, *feast* < French *feste,* *taste* < French *tast.* There doesn't seem to be any reason why some of these words are spelled with *ost* and others with *oast.*
- One word with a pronunciation that's hard to explain is *cost* /kɒst/  (or in different accents, /kɔst/ or /kɑst/), from Old French *cost, coust.* Two words with a similar etymology, *oust* (from Old French *ouster, oster*) and *joust* (from Old French *juster, joster, jouster*) are not pronounced the same way as *cost.* The Oxford English dictionary says that the modern pronunciation of *joust,* /jaʊst/, is based on the modern spelling, and that the regular development would be /dʒʌst/, as in *adjust.* Some of the Middle English spellings of *cost* listed in the OED, such as "coost," "coust" and "coast," seem to suggest that variant pronunciations with different vowels once existed.
- The word *accost* (from Middle French *acoster, accoster*) is also pronounced with /ɒst/ (or in different accents, /ɔst/ or /ɑst/), possibly due to association with *cost.* The Oxford English Dictionary says that the word was formerly associated with *coast,* and sometimes spelled with *oa,* so it's possible the pronunciation has changed over time.
- The word *provost* is sometimes pronounced with /əʊst/ in American English, but the Oxford English dictionary gives /ˈprɒvəst/ as its main British pronunciation. There is also variation in the pronunciation of the first vowel (maybe related to the similar variation in the pronunciation of words like *produce* and *progress*). This word has a very confused history, being borrowed into Old English and then "re-borrowed" to some extent later on. The ambiguous spelling probably contributed to the various pronunciations used in Modern English.

Something that I think is interesting is that there is similar ambiguity for words ending in  *oth*: *moth, broth* and *cloth* are pronounced with /ɒ/ (or in different accents, /ɔ/ or /ɑ/), , *both* is pronounced with a long dipthong /oʊ/, and *sloth, wroth* and *troth* can each be pronounced either way.